# Jms 2.0 inject context null in ejb

Tags: java, ejb

I'm new in working with JMS 2.0 as I'm try send a simple msg to the message Bean but here value of context is null all the time.

```
@Resource(mappedName = "jms/dest")
    private Queue dest;
    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("jms/queue")        
    private JMSContext context ;

private void sendJMSMessageToDest(String messageData)
{System.out.println("Msg = "+messageData );
System.out.println("Dest = "+dest );
System.out.println("Context  = " +context);
context.createProducer().send(dest, messageData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/JMS2.0WebMessage/JMS2.0WebMessage.html). I think you are trying to inject a destination (queue) with a Fractory annotation.

Comment: Sorry @kareless but it's not helping context is still null

Comment: @RahulChoudhary which container are you using, and have you checked the name of the JMS connection factory ?